# .net Application and IBM Websphere MQ Integration

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, windows

I am new to IBM Websphere MQ and trying to pass message from .net Application to WebSphere MQ which reside on Remote Box.

[i am trying the sample code provided on this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10490_.htm)

**My code is as below which is in Windows Application:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Collections;

namespace MQTest
{
class MQSample
{
    // The type of connection to use, this can be:-
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS for a server connection.
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT for a non-XA client connection
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT for an XA client connection
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED for a managed client connection
    const String connectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;

    // Define the name of the queue manager to use (applies to all connections)
    const String qManager = "QM785";

    // Define the name of your host connection (applies to client connections only)
  //  const String hostName = "NSL-D254(1785)";

    // Define the name of the channel to use (applies to client connections only)
 //   const String channel = "785.FIN.IDMS";



    /// <summary>
    /// Initialise the connection properties for the connection type requested
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionType">One of the MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_ values</param>
    static Hashtable init(String connectionType)
    {
        Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "NSL-D254(1785)");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "785.FIN.IDMS");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "NSLDC\truptir");
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "july@1234");

        // Add the connection type
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType);

        // Set up the rest of the connection properties, based on the
        // connection type requested
        switch (connectionType)
        {
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS:
                break;
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT:
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT:
            case MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED:
               // connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
              //  connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
                break;
        }

        return connectionProperties;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Hashtable connectionProperties = init(connectionType);
           // Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MQCCSID", "437");
            // Create a connection to the queue manager using the connection
            // properties just defined
            MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);

            // Set up the options on the queue we want to open
            int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;

            // Now specify the queue that we want to open,and the open options
            MQQueue system_default_local_queue =
              qMgr.AccessQueue("SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE", openOptions);

            // Define a WebSphere MQ message, writing some text in UTF format
            MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage();
            hello_world.WriteUTF("Hello World!");

            // Specify the message options
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the defaults,
            // same as MQPMO_DEFAULT

            // Put the message on the queue
            system_default_local_queue.Put(hello_world, pmo);



            // Get the message back again

            // First define a WebSphere MQ message buffer to receive the message
            MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
            retrievedMessage.MessageId = hello_world.MessageId;

            // Set the get message options
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions(); //accept the defaults
            //same as MQGMO_DEFAULT

            // Get the message off the queue
            system_default_local_queue.Get(retrievedMessage, gmo);

            // Prove we have the message by displaying the UTF message text
            String msgText = retrievedMessage.ReadUTF();
            Console.WriteLine("The message is: {0}", msgText);

            // Close the queue
            system_default_local_queue.Close();

            // Disconnect from the queue manager
            qMgr.Disconnect();
        }

        //If an error has occurred in the above,try to identify what went wrong.

        //Was it a WebSphere MQ error?
        catch (MQException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A WebSphere MQ error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }

        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A System error occurred: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }//end of start
}//end of sample

}
```

but i am getting following WebSphere MQ error
**MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE**

i pinged the remote computer from my development machine and vice versa which is working fine.

IBM WebSphere MQ settings:

-IBM WebSphere MQ is installed on Remote Machine

-Created Queue Manager

-Local Queue

-Server Connection channel (which shows inactive status)

-Under Server Connection channel Properties i have provide MCA User Id

-Listener status showing Running

Am i missing anything please let me know.

Comment: IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer Version: 7.5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to specify the port, the queue manager listener is configured on:

```
const String hostName = "NSL-D254(1414)";
```

1414 is the default, so better check it on the queue manager, and try it with telnet first.

Comment: i just tried that i am getting MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED exception but the thing is i have admin rights where MQ Server is installed

Comment: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED is better, now you can connect, but have no rights set. The user who runs the program needs permissions set on the queue manager.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501666/web-sphere-7-5-add-user/30515488#30515488) for more about the 2035. Basically, modern versions of MQ allow no remote connections by default, especially administrative ones. If you can't figure out how to authorize the connection with security enabled, ask another question with details and I'll respond.

Comment: i made some changes in ConnectionProperties HashTable  connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "NSL-D254");
 connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "785.FIN.IDMS");
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "NSLDC\truptir");
            connectionProperties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "july@1234"); Also i have mentioned MCA User Id property in my channel and now i am getting MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE Exception.

Comment: Have you lost the port number again? Also, when you get back to the 2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED) return code, make sure you look in the AMQERR01.LOG on the queue manager and copy the error message that explains more about the reason why you got said error, and then we can help you further.

Comment: You have the port number in one line early on in your program, but you don,t have it where you ar setting up the hashtable. I suspect the line where you have added it is a redundant line in your program?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but we recently had a similar issue with a test application using 7.0.1.4 and found the underlying assemblies are including the username running the application in the connection packet.

To fix this, we ran the application with [PSExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) as system user. Voila, the connections started working again. The legacy production service is also running as LocalSystem so it is passing System as the user.

Comment: Note that in this case you are simply asserting to MQ that your program is running as that user.  With the Java API it is trivial to present any user as the user running the application, so your only security on the Queue manager side is that the program connecting asserts it is running as a specific user, this is very easy to spoof.  With modern MQ version 8.0 and later (also 8.0 and later at the only currently supported versions from IBM) you can pass id and password to the queue manager, the queue manager can validate those and use the authenticated id for authoriation checks.

Comment: @JoshMc, unfortunately, we were using the C# client assemblies and the vendor queue only had permissions for the System user. When we did set the UserId for the connection, both the logged in User and stated user were sent over, above was the only way to send the right user in both fields.


Moving to 8.0 would have simplified our testing, but was not possible in the time frame given.